# Bash: Unable to replace bold text with plain text in a string using Sed

Tags: bash, sed, printf

I've a string in bash containing bold text and I want to replace it with plain text. Basically, I am trying to use sed to replace '\e[3m' (bold) and '\e[0m' (plain) escape sequences with empty strings. I am able to convert a normal text to bold text but opposite is not working. Here is the code:

```
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ normal=$'\e[0m'
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ bold=$'\e[1m'
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ str="Patience is Virtue"
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ strbold=$(echo $str | sed s"/Patience/${bold}Patience${normal}/g")
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ printf %q "$strbold"; echo
$'\E[1mPatience\E[0m is Virtue'
```

On giving command echo -e "$strbold" above is working fine and displaying the word "Patience" in bold, but when trying to do the opposite, it's not working.

```
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ strplain=$(echo "$strbold" | sed s"/${bold}//g")
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ strplain=$(echo "$strbold" | sed s"/\\e\[1m//g")
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ printf %q "$strplain"; echo
$'\E[1mPatience\E[0m is Virtue'
```

Can you please let me know how to replace these bold and normal escape sequences in a string with empty strings using Sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a var with bold/normal and use regular expressions:

```
format=$'\e\[(0|1)m'
sed -r "s/${format}//g" <<< "$strbold"
```

Comment: I tried your way and it almost worked, but still when I am printing the output with %q option of printf, I am getting 2 unwanted backslashes. One after 'Patience' and one after 'is'. Below is the code:

`swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ format=$'\e\[(0|1)m'
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ printf %q "$strbold"; echo
$'\E[1mPatience\E[0m is Virtue'
swady@DESKTOP-QAVQ17K:~$ printf %q "$(sed -r "s/${format}//g" <<< "$strbold")"; echo
Patience\ is\ Virtue
`

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. When we do printf with %q for a string, it prefix spaces with backslash. So, that's perfectly normal. Which means, your solution is absolutely fantastic, what I wanted. Accepting the answer.